# Idiotic jQuery prev/next button utilization for slider/carousel implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel

I have an image carousel. There's a div for the main viewing area, and then a div containing an unordered list for a bunch of thumbnails. You click a thumbnail, it shows it full-size in the main viewing div. Easy enough.

Here's a screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YEyp6.png

But I'm also trying to implement "**previous/next**" buttons, and how to do this is evading me right now.

As you can see, the current slide is given a class to give it an orange outline.

Each thumbnail also has a unique ID.

How on earth can I click prev/next and retrieve the actual ID of the element possessing the **"activeThumb" class**?

Thanks for any pointers in the right direction.

Edit for clarification:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a id="01"><img class="activeSlide" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="02"><img class="inactiveSlide" /></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a id="03"><img class="inactiveSlide" /></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Using a selector as such:

```
$('li img [class="activeSlide"]').parent('a').attr('id');
```

returns undefined.

ANSWER: the following syntax returns the correct ID:

```
$('img.activeSlide').parent('a').attr('id');
```

Comment: The [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method returns a jQuery object, not a boolean value. What makes you think otherwise?

Comment: Next time please include HTML and JavaScript. That way you will get concerete answers and not only guesses.

Comment: Gah, you're correct. hasClass() was the boolean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried

```
$('.activeThumb').parent('a').attr('id')
```

If there is only one element with class activeThumb this should return you the id of the active element.

**Update**: Updated Answer to include comment.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified also; the structure of the thumbnails is as such:

<ul>
<li>
<a id="whateverUniqueId"><img class="activeSlide" /></a>
</li>

Comment: $('li img [class="activeSlide"]').blah()

Comment: Corrected syntax in the question post, but yeah, this worked, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

so

```
$('.activeThumb').parent('a').attr('id')
```

then..

Comment: or .activeSlide whatever your class name is